# My tires are 700x23/25C. What does 23/25 mean?

Tags: tire

My bike uses a tire size of 700x23/25C. I understand that the 700 indicates the diameter of the rim. 23 is supposed to be the width of the tread which I believe means 23 mm, am I right? So what does the 25c mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "c" in bicycle tire size mean?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/what-does-the-c-in-bicycle-tire-size-mean)

Comment: @ojs nope - that's not a dupe because this is about two numbers for the tyre size, and not specifically about the c.

Comment: Can you tell us what manufacturer and model your current tire is, and perhaps include a picture of the size info printed or embossed on the sidewall?

Comment: Keep in mind that 2mm is hardly measurable.  You can't get a repeatable measurement more accurate than that, especially on different rims.

Answer (score 3):

Some manufacturers (e.g., Specialize) offer two width measurements (e.g., 700x23/25c) to indicate that the carcass is 25 mm wide, but that the tread patch is equivalent to a 23 mm tire.  I believe this is done to create a more supple tire (larger volume tires can be run at a lower pressure) while reducing rolling resistance.

Another possibility could be to indicate width/height profile differences. A tire profile that is perfectly found tire will be the same in both. I don't know if any manufacturers are doing this.

Comment: Another possibility is that the actual width of a tyre in use depends on the width of the rim it is mounted on. I haven't come across a manufacturer labelling then with a range though.

Comment: @armb I think a hyphen would make more sense to indicate a range. Slashes usually indicates a duality.